# Log shipping option not showing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, log-shipping

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition. I am trying to implement log shipping, but the log shipping option is not showing in the database properties window. The database recovery option is `bulk logged`.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the "Database Properties" window?

Comment: In  the properties window the last page select is extended properties. And i dont know how to insert a image in the comment it look like only text is accepting

Comment: You can insert an image into the body of your question (just hit the "edit" button).

Comment: Do you have proper permissions?

Comment: which permission do you mean? #kin

Comment: The properties window images is added #Thomas String

Comment: It also requires some common share folders where you need to specify proper permissions

Comment: #Ashish can you please specify which all common folder

Comment: What is the database ID for the one you are working with?

Comment: Also permissions required are sysadmin role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shyamev,

Just to make sure the database selected should be a user and not any system databases.

But in many cases we have seen this even if its user database is selected and the option of log shipping is missing.

Solution: Re-install SSMS with the Management Tools - Complete option checked.

Refer to below link:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/01a0ab24-5555-4b55-b399-a866a5b09d1d/transaction-log-shipping-option-is-missing